# Android NDK: Host ' awk' tool is outdated. Please define NDK_HOST_AWK to point to gawk or nawk

Tags: android, awk, android-ndk

I am getting following message when I try to build my project which is using native code with NDK r9d version in command prompt on Windows 7:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "D:/OSAMAS_THINGS/Softwares/Android_NDK_R9D/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r9d/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/awk.exe -f D:/OSAMAS_THINGS/Softwares/Android_NDK_R9D/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r9d/build/awk/check-awk.awk", ...) failed.
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool is outdated. Please define NDK_HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or Nawk !
D:/OSAMA'S_THINGS/Softwares/Android_NDK_R9D/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/init.mk:376: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

When I rename `awk.exe` to `awk_.exe` in `...\android-ndk-r9d\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin` folder, I get the following message:

```
'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool is outdated. Please define NDK_HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or Nawk !
D:/OSAMA'S_THINGS/Softwares/Android_NDK_R9D/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/init.mk:376: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

I tried other answers on stackoverflow, but that did not solved the problem.
In both the cases I am getting error.
Please help me solve the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met same issue, I also checked stackoverflow comment and changed.
But, I couldn't this issue.
I doubted 64bit ndk.
Anyway, I changed 64bit ndk to 32bit and cygwin also.
and Then I solved issue. 
Have a niceday

Answer (score 1):

It's *probably* complaining because the `awk` you're using doesn't have the capabilities it needs.

Of course, it may be deciding this based simply on the *name* so the first thing I'd do is rename what you currently have to `gawk.exe` and then use `NDK_HOST_AWK` to reference it.

If that doesn't work, I suggest you head on over to [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) and pick up the `gawk` install package.